# SoftLayer API: ordering bandwidth pool

Tags: bandwidth, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For N/W Part, when we tried to 'add' the new bandwidth pool, there was 25$ fee for the installation.
But I failed to find API to call that fee.
Even there'was no ID that required 25$ setup fee.

What do I have to use for adjusting that installation fee?

Please I want to know how to code,
'Adding Bandwidth Pool' in java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the following Java Scripts:

**1.** To get the Bandwidhth Pool's fee for add Vdr Member/Installation:

```
package SoftLayer.api_java;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.account.Attribute;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;

/** 
 * This script retrieves a Vdr Member Price
 * 
 * Important pages:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAttributeByType
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Account_Attribute
 */
public class GetVdrMemberPrice {

    public GetVdrMemberPrice() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String user = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";
        // Declare API Client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apikey);
        // Declare the type of account attribute you wish to retrieve
        String attributeType = "VDR_MEMBER_PRICE";
        try {
            Attribute result = Account.service(client).getAttributeByType(attributeType);
            System.out.println("Value: " + result.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetVdrMemberPrice();
    }
}
```

**2.** To add Bandwidth Pool

```
package SoftLayer.api_java;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.bandwidth.version1.Allotment;

/**
 * Add a Bandwidth Pool
 * 
 * Important pages:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment/createObject
 */
public class AddingBandwidthPool {

    public AddingBandwidthPool() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String user = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";
        // Define your account Id (set me)
        Long accountId = new Long(123456);
        // Define an identifier marking this allotment as a virtual private rack (1) or a bandwidth pooling(2).
        Long bandwidthAllotmentTypeId = new Long(2);
        // Define the region. You can get available regions using SoftLayer_Location_Group::getAllObjects method
        // http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group/getAllObjects
        Long locationGroupId = new Long(1); 
        // Define text a virtual rack's name.
        String name = "set me";
        // Declare API Client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apikey);
        // Build a SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment object that you wish to create
        Allotment templateObject = new Allotment();
        templateObject.setAccountId(accountId);
        templateObject.setBandwidthAllotmentTypeId(bandwidthAllotmentTypeId);
        templateObject.setLocationGroupId(locationGroupId);;
        templateObject.setName(name);

        try {
            boolean result = Allotment.service(client).createObject(templateObject);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddingBandwidthPool();
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is an issue with the return value for: SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment::createObject, because according to [wsdl](https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment?wsdl), it returns a boolean, but it is returning a SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment object. However, the bandwidth pool is added successfully.

References:
[GetVdrMemberPrice](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAttributeByType)
[CreateBandwidthPool](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment/createObject)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. :) helped a lot. So, for adding the banding pool, I have to create the new 'Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment'. right? And according to the flow, after creating one, then have to add server then the installation fee will be adjusted. I'm on concerning about adding installation fee on the bill. How can I add that fee on billing item?    Thanks. (And fyi, we are on working with Java)

Comment: Yes, you are right about the flow. Regarding to adding the fee on the bill, this will be added automatically, the transaction will run a new billing item that it should show up.

Comment: This is a fee established for your account, you can get this value (The fee to add Vdr member/ installation) using the first script that I sent "1. To get the Bandwidhth Pool's fee for add Vdr Member/Installation.", Did you try with that?

Comment: Hello, We've tried with your first answer for getting the 'fee information', as below ,

try {
 accountService.clearMask();
 client = restApiClient.withCredentials(userId, apiKey);
 Attribute result = Account.service(client).getAttributeByType("VDR_MEMBER_PRICE");
 //com.softlayer.api.service.account.Attribute result = accountService.getAttributeByType("VDR_MEMBER_PRICE");
 System.out.println("Value : " + result.getValue());
} catch (Exception e) {
 // TODO: handle exception
 e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: And we got the null pointer exception. The value of 'VDR Member Price' was null. Could you give us the further help? Thanks.

Comment: If you got a null pointer exception, it means that this attribute doesn't exist in your account and the "VDR MEMBER PRICE" is set by default ($25.00). In some cases when a customer or account has a different price, the script that you tried, should return the set price.